# cant reference array class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a class consisting of a nested array called twoDArray.

```
  public class TestArray 
  {

  public function TestArray() {

  var twoDArray:Array = new Array(new Array("one","two"), new Array("three", "four"));
  } 

  }
```

I have another class which attempts to make a variable of type TestArray.

```
  var OrbArray:TestArray = new TestArray();
```

I thought I would be able to reference OrbArray for example using trace(OrbArray[0][0]); giving me the output I am looking for of "one". When I attempt this I get ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on com.orbclasses.TestArray and there is no default value. Help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
public dynamic class TestArray extends Array
{

  public function TestArray()
  {
    push(new Array("one", "two"), new Array("three", "four"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `TestArray` class:

```
public class TestArray
{
  public var twoDArray:Array = null;

  public function TestArray()
  {
    twoDArray = new Array(new Array("one", "two"), new Array("three", "four"));
  }
}
```

Note: `twoDArray` is publicly accessible.

Now when you want to access it:

```
var testArray:TestArray = new TestArray();
trace("output:", testArray.twoDArray[0][0]);
```

i.e. you try to access the property `twoDArray` which belongs to `testArray`.

If you want to do `testArray[0][0]` for some reason, you can do that too, but for that you'll have to look at the `flash.utils.Proxy` class.